# Odd Conversion between UIColor and CGColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, cgcolor

So here are the colors I am trying to convert from UIColor to CGColor:

## 001385 - R:0 G:19 B:133

## ca000b - R:202 G:0 B:11

Here is the Blue vs. iOS's rendering:
a:[image]
b:[image]

Here is the Red vs. iOS's rendering: a[image: <code>enter image description here</code>] b: [image]

Here is the code I am using to convert the colors:
Red:

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:202 green:0 blue:11 alpha:1] CGColor]
```

Blue:

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:19 blue:133 alpha:1] CGColor]
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Read the docs for `UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to divide the parameters by 255.0. As noted by @Duncan C, ensure you are dividing by 255.0

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:202.0/255.0 green:0 blue:11/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]


[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:19/255.0 blue:133/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]
```

Comment: Ok, so I guess the parameters should only go from 0 to 1. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Make sure yo divide by 255.0. This forces the math to be in floating point, and return decimal values. If you divide by 255, it's likely to do integer math and give you zero for anything less than 255/255.

Answer (score 3):

A handy Category to add to UIColor:

Then you can do for example: `[UIColor R:0 G:19 B:133]`

```
@interface UIColor (RGB)

+(UIColor*)R:(NSUInteger)r G:(NSUInteger)g B:(NSUInteger)b;
+(UIColor*)R:(NSUInteger)r G:(NSUInteger)g B:(NSUInteger)b A:(CGFloat)a;

@end

@implementation UIColor (RGB)

+(UIColor*)R:(NSUInteger)r G:(NSUInteger)g B:(NSUInteger)b {
     return [self R:r G:g B:b A:1.0];
}

+(UIColor*)R:(NSUInteger)r G:(NSUInteger)g B:(NSUInteger)b A:(CGFloat)a {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)r)/255.0 green:((CGFloat)g)/255.0 blue:((CGFloat)b)/255.0 alpha:a];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 5, you can use [UIColor's `getRed(_:green:blue:alpha)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621919-getred) method (here shown in Swift):

```
var red: CGFloat = 0
var green: CGFloat = 0
var blue: CGFloat = 0
var alpha: CGFloat = 0

let color = UIColor.systemGreen
// getRed(_:green:blue:alpha) returns 'true' on successful conversion
if color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
{
    print("red: \(red)\ngreen: \(green)\nblue: \(blue)\nalpha: \(alpha)")
}

/*
which for `systemGreen` in light mode prints:
red: 0.20392156862745098
green: 0.7803921568627451
blue: 0.34901960784313724
alpha: 1.0
*/
```

and, as a computed property in an extension to `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
    var rgbaComponents: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0

        getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        return (red, green, blue, alpha)
    }
}
```